# Google Calendar API can't get calendars

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API and it is working fine but when i am trying to get all Google calendars. I am getting Blank array Although i have calendars in my google account. If try to get events of any particular calendar then it shows me all listed events of this particular event.

Here is my Code:-
`

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
// Defining basic parameters

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Google Sheets API PHP Quickstart');

define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', __DIR__ .'/credentials/calendar-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(  Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR,Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY)
));
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.CREDENTIALS_PATH);
function getClient(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
    $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
    return $client;
}
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($calendarList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Response is:-

```
Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarList Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => items
    [etag] => "p33kcficlivodi0g"
    [itemsType:protected] => Google_Service_Calendar_CalendarListEntry
    [itemsDataType:protected] => array
    [kind] => calendar#calendarList
    [nextPageToken] => 
    [nextSyncToken] => COjHyZWX8NkCEkBnYW1lci1zaGVkdWxhckB0ZXN0c2VydmljZS0xNDcwNjUzMTI0Njg5LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29t
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [items] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: 1. which type of credentials did you create?  2. listCalendarList only lists the ones that appear in the bottom left of the google calendar web view.  Not necessarily all the calender's you have access to.

Comment: Thankx Dalm for replying. I have followed the "https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php" . And after that tried many codes but none of them working

Comment: Actually what exactly i have to do is 1. Get all the Google calendars and display them in a dropdown 2. User will select any calendar from them and add their event in this Calendar..

Comment: If its returning  nothing then the user has no access to no calendars which makes me think you are using a service account.   At the very least normal Google users will have a primary calendar listed.   Try and authenticate it again make sure you are using the correct user to login

Comment: Dalmto, Do you have any reference..?

Comment: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Calendar%20API  and https://www.daimto.com/accessing-google-calendar-with-php-oauth2/

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
```

With:

```
$client->setAuthConfig(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
```

And add this:

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

Comment: t Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" }

Comment: which credentials do you use when you successfully get your events?

Comment: $calendarId = 'bh3j6b48ine1bi0ags046svjs4@group.calendar.google.com';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
echo "</pre>";
//echo $results->getSummary();

foreach ($results->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
  }

Comment: I added another line of code in my answer did that work?

Comment: So for events your using these credentials: CREDENTIALS_PATH

Comment: In CREDENTIALS_PATH i have service account json file

Comment: and CLIENT_SECRET_PATH auth ID json

Comment: I agree with @DaImTo.  A way to test this would be to try to insert a calendar using those credentials, and then run your code again and see if it shows up in the calendar list.  You may need to adjust your scopes to allow the insert of the new calendar as it looks like yours are read only.

Comment: How many calendars do you have in the bottom left of the google calendar when you login to your bh3j6b48ine1bi0ags046svjs4@group.calendar.google.com account.\

Comment: I have 5 calendars. .And when i try with Google Explorer it shows me list of all calendars

Comment: Try to insert a calendar using https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert

Comment: Joseph when i try to insert any calendar it gives me error " Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in /home/randelation/public_html/api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: #0 /"

Comment: did you change your scopes so you can add a calendar?

Comment: Here is a list of errors - read the 404: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors

Comment: Joseph, As i use the " developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert" when i add "$calendarListEntry->setId("bh3j6b48ine1bi0ags046svjs4@group.calendar.google.com");"  it gives me all details of this particular calendar. .

Comment: make a fake calendar name   ex:  $calendarListEntry->setId('Test')

Comment: I did that getting error " Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "message": "Not Found" } ], "code": 404, "message": "Not Found" } } in /home/randelation/public_html/api/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118 Stack trace: ". And if i try it with Google Explorer still getting the error

Comment: Keep in mind trying to insert a calendar to the calendar list was a test to see if we could then retrieve the new calendar from the code that you originally posted.  Obviously, we are running into problems trying to insert the calendar.  I am out of ideas.  You need to make sure that there are calendars that exist inside of your bh3j6b48ine1bi0ags046svjs4@group.calendar.google.com account.  And that you are using the correct credentials when your set up the client.  Good luck!

Comment: I messed up.. I was telling you to use the insert for the calendar list.  Try inserting a calendar by this method:  https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars

Comment: Hey Joseph, I tried insert calendar it reverts me id "ukfdm5pe26rd2c9mv2pf0ujok4@group.calendar.google.com"

Comment: Joseph i can get the calendars which i made by Code. .  What its mean..

Comment: But i can not see them in my google calendar account.. Where are they placing..?

Comment: I'm thinking that you are using a service account as already suggested above by DalmTo.  Read this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451846/google-calendar-api-on-php-using-service-account

Comment: is it related to Gsuite. .?

Comment: If you are using Gsuite I would say most likely yes.  I do not have experience with gsuite.  An application I made used OAuth2 verification for access to client calendars.  I would read both and decide what is best for you application requirements and goals.

Comment: Yaa thank you. I do not know about Gsuite. Actually what exactly i have to do is 1. Get all gmail calendars of logged in user and display them in a dropdown 2. User will select any calendar from them and add event in this Calendar..

Comment: The calendar that you are getting is it the user's own personal calendar, or a calendar that you are going to create for the user?

Comment: I have to setup api like when a user comes to my site i have to pull all calendars of this user and show in the dropdown. .

Comment: If I already have my own gmail calendar and I log into your site and you want to get access to my calendar and display it in a drop down menu then you will want to use OAuth2.

Comment: Yes Joseph.... I want the exactly.. Do you have any reference for this. .

Comment: Thoroughly study this page.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: Hey Joseph. .I have setup the OAuth2 and now it is working for me. . Thank you for your Time. You helped me alot. . :)